# How to make div scale vertically all the way down?

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation, presented in the picture. Grey div is the parent of magenta and blue divs. Magenta div scales vertically with the content. I would like to have blue div always scale to the bottom of the containing grey, div. I've searched and tried various combinations, but all to nil effect.

[image]

edit:
Problem solved! Container needs an overflow: hidden, and the div that I want to stretch to the bottom (blue) needs padding-bottom: 1000px; margin-bottom: -1000; (or larger if you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need support from IE6 and up, the answer is: You can´t in css only.

There are different solutions to really scale the div or just have it appear like that:

1. You can use a background-image for the grey div (if all you need is the background to stretch all the way down)
2. You can use javascript to calculate the height of the grey div and apply it to the blue div

There is a ccs option using a very big padding and an equally big negative margin, but I don´t remember if it works for all browsers and I can't find the article right now.

**Edit:** The big padding / negative margin css solution:

The article is talking about Firefox 1.5 and Safari 2 so I don't know if it still works, but [here it is](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61).

Comment: I remember that solution with big negative margin - I have used that once before, but for the love of god I can't remember the exact implementation details nor can I find it online!

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work (in Chrome anyway) by setting the parent's div:

```
position: absolute;
```

and the child's div:

```
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience setting the height of the blue DIV to 100% doesn't work. The only time that I have wanted this was to have the blue DIV with it's own background, to solve this you need to just have the background of the gray DIV include the blue background of the other DIV.

Comment: aka faux column - I'm trying to avoid that though, since in my current setup I'd need to add another div container... if nothing else shows up, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript to do it would be...

```
<div id="yourDiv" style="background-color: Blue; width: 150px;">
    Hello
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById('yourDiv');

    div.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
</script>
```

Edit:

Check [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) link for getting clientHeight in different browsers...

Comment: Any particular reason why javascript isn't an option? If you have jquery available you could do something like 
var greydiv = $("#greydivselector").height();
$("#bluedivselector").height(greydiv);
And you could play around with offsets. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree, why isnt JavaScript an option? Probably an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your parent div, if you set "float:right" on your blue div and play around with your height in percent (height:100%;), I think you should achieve what you're asking.

Since the blue div is a child of your grey div, the maximum height of your blue div shouldn't exceed your parent div. Unless I'm missing something here...

Also, if you are floating your blue div on the right, be sure to place it before the magenta div in your markup.

Acorn

Comment: Don't forget to specify the height of the parent, or the floated items won't 'stay inside' of the parent

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set height 100% in html objects is use styles:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
     html, body { 
   height: 100%; 
}

#mydiv { 
   height: 100%; 
   background-color:red; 
}           
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">aaa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For child objects to work with 100% height, the parent must have a fix height

Comment: I did paste your HTML.  It doesn't cover the question very well.

Comment: Maybe because i don't defined margins in body, try put after height:100%, margin: 0 0 0 0; in body css

Answer (score 0):

The key is to have a set height on the parent container.  Then the height:100% works

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Divs</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
#main {
    height:30em;
    width:30em;
    background-color:#999999;
    padding:1em 1em 0px 1em;
}
.inner {
    width:5em;
}
#blue {
    float:right;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    height:100%;
}
#magenta {
    float:left;
    background-color:magenta;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div class="inner" id="blue">
        1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10
    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="magenta">
        1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, but what if I don't know the height of the parent up front? I want it to scale with left div content... I wonder why wouldn't a min-height work as well in this situation, must be some kind of an oversight.