# Div columns not extending to bottom of content when floated left and right

Tags: css, height, overflow, clearfix

I have two divs/columns. One floated left and the other floated right (it needs to be this way for a responsive design page I'm making). The content of the left div extends far below the viewport/left div, while the right content is shorter and stays well within the viewport/right div.

I need the background colors to expand all the way to the bottom of the left div's content (or right div's content if it was the longer one).

Instead, it's cutting of the background colors/div right at the bottom of the viewport.
I've tried clears:both's, clearfix, and overflow controls to no avail. I imagine I'm not implementing them correctly for this setup. Can anyone edit my fiddle to show me what I need to do to get them to extend to the bottom?

Here's the fiddle (you'll need to scroll down in the little viewport to see how it cuts off the colors):

http://jsfiddle.net/4C89C/

Here's the code I'm using in the fiddle:

```
<html><head></head><body><style>

html, body {height:100%;}
#content {
    height:100%;
    border:thin solid red;
}
#innerdiv {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 60%;
}
#innerdiv2 {
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 40%;
}
#textdiv {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
#textdiv2 {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    colo: white;
}  
</style>




<div id="content">
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <div id="textdiv">

Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />

                </div>
    </div>

<div id="innerdiv2">
        <div id="textdiv2">

Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />
            </div>
      </div>    
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`#content { height:100%; }` does not work because this height refers to the parent element's height and not the height "produced" by `#content`'s content... which means `#content` only gets as high as `<body>` is, which again is not the entire height of the page, but rather the height of the "displayed area".

Don't define any height for `#content` and after `#innerdiv2` insert another `<div>` with `height:0;` and `clear:both;`.

Should do the trick and not disturb you or anyone for that matter :)

Comment: Hi, I tried as you suggested but it's only expanding the left all the way down. How do I get the right side's color to go all the way down too? Here's the updated fiddle with your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/SGzC3/

Comment: Am I inserting the height:0; and clear:both; div in the wrong place somehow? I've tried it everywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your question carefully enough. I thought you wanted to stretch the surrounding `<div>`. Stretching the blue one will give you a hard time, that's for sure, because the parent div does not have any height defined. You'll see the blue one strech if you define a height for `#content`... but that's not what we want. I am testing a few things, but I'll have to get up early (I'm in Europe)... so I might just reply something more or less useful tomorrow. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's weird, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4C89C/5/ 

Added a padding to the blue `<div>` and the same margin, but negative, as well as overflow:hidden to #content. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065408/how-to-make-div-scale-vertically-all-the-way-down).

Comment: I'm not sure the negative margin is actually necessary... Anyone with a different opinion?

Comment: That's a clever solution for some situations, and thanks for your help. But if there's little to no content then it cut's short when you'd want it to at least be as tall as the full viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/dK3tC/

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to specify that it be at least the length of the body in that situation where there's little to no text in either div.

Comment: To be honest, I feel like what you are trying to accomplish in your last comment is not possible with CSS only. I also feel you would need to play around with `position:absolute;`, however, if you use that with the blue `<div>`, the red one won't stretch, because, well, that's how it works.. 

Heights in `<div>`'s are always a tricky thing and everything that involves anything remotely resembling a 100% height can be a big pain in the a**.

The easiest way might be to **trick** the visitor into believing the blue `<div>` is stretched, by using a cleverly positioned, repeating background image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dK3tC/2/ 

The problem with this one: it doesn't stretch the red one (makes sense, after its height is set to 100%) and, although min-height, stretches the red one for itself, it does not "pass along" the red divs height to the inner divs, so they don't know what they're supposed to do with a height:100%; since their parent element does not really have a height defined.